# How to sort by defined order in sas, not alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, sas

Say I have a dataset for a supermarket,  with a product category, price product name etc. I want to sort by the category but with a defined order as opposed to alphabetically.

For instance if the categories are: canned, dairy, meat,  vegetable,  and I want to sort by when they may expire (I'll it's likely we'd have that information, so just play along please).  This means I want to sort in this order: Dairy, Meat, Vegetable, Canned.

I wrote a macro with this signature:

```
key_sort(ds=, keys='canned, dairy, meat,  vegetable', field =category, sort_by=)
```

This parses the keys so that the can be put in a macro loop,  then I use that much loop to write out a select statement like so:

```
Select(&field. ) ;
    %do i=1 %to &number_of_keys. ;
    %let current_key= %scan(&keys., &I., &delim.) ;
    When(&current_key. ) &field._key=&i. ;
    %end;
End;
```

I then sort by the  `&field._key`
Is this the best method to take? Can this be done more succinctly or efficiently?

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable approach. Essentially you need to put a numeric value which defines the relative order of the categories you are interested in. And then sort by that numeric value instead of the categories.

Comment: I suppose the other option is to merge that numeric number on.

Comment: @Pureferret my SAS is a bit rusty and I don't have a SAS system installed to test... Anwyay... The proc format is okay, but I believe proc sort doesn't take a formatted value into consideration for sorting... So, in effect, you can use a `format` as a mini-lookup time, and do the sort on the formatted value using sql and a temporary variable...

Comment: Or just use the `put(produce_type, $expires.)` inside the creation of your dataset to create your order field and `proc sort` normally on that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had a separate dataset that contained the ordering then you could utilise that and provide it as input a PROC FORMAT, or apply one that's only a few bits as simply as possible.

```
proc format; 
    value $EXPIRES 
        'canned'= 4
        'dairy' = 1
        'meat' = 2
        'vegetable' = 3
        other = 5
        ;
run; 

proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE output_set AS 
    SELECT * FROM foods ORDER BY put(produce_type, $expires.); 
quit;
```